# Graphics on boot like the backtrack linux or the Gentoo live DVD after you press alt+F1 on boot

Tags: gentoo, graphics, tty, bootsplash

Would like to find a good tutorial on how to make a boot splash similar to the one on backtrack {3,4,5}. It has all of the terminal text that you would see on a normal boot up but it has a nice border. Another example is the gentoo live DVD, a picturesque title bar that has the Gentoo logo on it. It seems to me that it is able to put the graphics into the virtual console. I would like to find a way to make programs take advantage of this and make my boot up screen look cooler as well.

I'm running gentoo X86_64 with GCC -v gcc version 4.6.3 (Gentoo 4.6.3 p1.6, pie-0.5.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backtrack 5 uses old-fashion bootsplash (the nice border) plus plymouth, BT{3,4} use bootsplash only (it support a verbose mode and silent mode, that means a background picture plus boot progress bar)

But gentoo now ships with fbsplash by default.

You will need to patch the kernel with latest bootsplash patch and plymouth (Install the userland tool as well), I don't think this has official support as this moment, good luck with ti. But you might just copy the kernel source code shipped with BT5 (in /usr/src/linux-source-3.2-*)

P.S: fbsplash / bootsplash suffers a slow output, e.g try `man ls` in the framebuffer, you're likely to screen flashes. I stopped using them for a long time, it only server to slow down booting.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not looking to slow my boot time down though I hardly ever shut my computer down.